# How can I access and modify a website's HTML locally using code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a program that looks through the website you're on, and censors bad words. I can use CTRL-shift-c to pull up Chrome Dev tools, and go through each element and erase the words I don't want easily enough, but how might I do that with code?

I understand a little about web-scrapping using beautifulsoup, so finding the no no words should be simple enough, but I have no idea how to give that program the ability to edit the HTML of the website.

I'm thinking there are two solutions; I can scrape each element for its text, and then re-insert the new text in its place, or I would have to snatch a copy of the website's HTML, have my code scan and edit it, and then upload this new HTML in its place?

The more I think about it the less feasible it seems.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why would you lower yourself to become a webscraper? that won't change what you see in your browser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I know what you might want, something akin to find and replace, I tried to sketch up something quick in Python:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def find_and_replace(html_content, keyword, replacement):
    # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

    # Find all elements containing the keyword
    elements_with_keyword = soup.find_all(lambda tag: keyword.lower() in tag.get_text().lower() if tag.name else False)

    # Replace the content of each found element
    for element in elements_with_keyword:
        element.string = replacement

    return str(soup)

# Read the HTML file
file_path = "example.html"
with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    html_content = file.read()

# Specify the keyword you want to find and the replacement text
keyword_to_find = "example"
replacement_text = "poop"

# Find and replace the keyword in the HTML content
modified_html_content = find_and_replace(html_content, keyword_to_find, replacement_text)

# Write the modified content back to the file
with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(modified_html_content)

print(f'Keyword "{keyword_to_find}" replaced with "{replacement_text}" in the file "{file_path}".')
```

Of course, if you have multiple words, you might want to use a for loop and a list for that, but that is up to you.

I think I forgot to mention this is local HTML only, if you want something for the web ( client side ) I suggest dabbling into extensions ( as in they will only be censored by the one using the extension or something like that ) well, I think I got downvoted because I just gave you some code but, here is some example of what you could achieve: chromewebstore.google.com/detail/censor-me/… read this for more info : developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/get-started/tutorial/… using plain old javascript should be enough.

Comment: Yes this is great, exactly what I was looking for! The find and replace replaced everything with a single line of "poop", but with a few changes I think I'll get it to work. Now all I have to do is code up a way to override the current website's html with my version. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I just updated the answer hope it helps.